# jquery scrollview: How to know when scroll ended?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, scrollview

i've been playing with the scrollview that was made for jquery mobile, so far it seems to be working fine for me BUT i need to understand where can i add a callback for when the scrolling ended. I have tried unsuccessfully in some parts of the code. I would very much appreciate some guidance here.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have access to the

`scrollstart` and `scrollstop`

events

Example (Doesn't work in a desktop browser, need to test on device)

- http://jsfiddle.net/52EzR/1/

JS

```
$("#theList").scrollstop(function(event) {
    alert('Event: ' + event.type + ' pageX ' + event.pageX + ' pageY ' + event.pageY);
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page"> 
    <h2>Long list for scrolling</h2> 
    <div data-role="content">        
        <ul data-role="listview" id="theList"> 
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>10</li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
</div>
```